# Invalid syntax.. missing [] - but no?

Tags: pycharm

I try to run my code in PyCharm and I got that invalid syntax, complaining that it missing a ] just before the first parantes.

Why? I only have two [[ ]] - brackets, and the last ] one is in the end of that line.

/ Best

```
import random

#Set up the grid;

class grid(object):
    def __init__(self, mines, grid_size):
        self.mines = mines
        self.grid = grid[['0' for i in range(int(grid_size))] for i in range(int(grid_size))] #"null matrix"
        mines = place_mines(grid, mines) #place where the mines should be randomly
        for i,j in mines:
            grid[i][j]="x" #i row, j colomn
        grid=number(grid)
        return (grid, mines)
```

And the output is:

```
  File "/Users/,/Deskop/minröj ej klas/minrlj klass.py", line 8
    self.grid = grid[['0' for i in range(int(grid_size))] for i in range(int(grid_size))] #"null matrix"
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `grid` that should not be there:

```
self.grid = [['0' for i in range(int(grid_size))] for i in range(int(grid_size))] #"null matrix"
```

The list comprehensions syntax (the one you use) is as follow:

```
foo = ["bar" for item in iterable]
```

Therefore, you are simply not using the syntax as it should be used.

Comment: aaaah thanks! 
may I ask why it shouldn't / couldn't be there?

Comment: Sure. Explanation added in the answer.